# Uninstalling kodi

Tags: 16.04

I started to install kodi then cancelled now when I boot up kodi takes over screen not ubuntu.  Cant  access ubuntu desk top  to surf the web or to do anything. 
Need help to remove kodi.  Note, I cant access the app store.  Cant boot up ubuntu computer opens in kodi instead of ubuntu

Comment: How did you installed Kodi ? Which version of it ?

Comment: 17.10 loaded from windows ( hope I answered the question.  I am new to ubuntu (linux)

Comment: Computer boots right into kodi. I tried ctrl alt F4 but was unable to log in.

Comment: Kodi was installed from the ubuntu app store.

Comment: If you logout, you will be returned to the login screen, where you can select the DEsktop (ie. Ubuntu, Kodi & whatever else you've added). Look for a gear logo (*your used dm dictates what to look for*).  Note: *if you have auto-login with no password, you are missing this selection step & get whatever you set as default or selected last time. You select Kodi or desktop @ login*